# How to enable access control for CIFS mount point available for multiple users?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, cifs

I have a samba server configured with multiple users.

By default, mounted cifs shares only use the credentials provided at mount. Everyone who can access the mount point accesses the files as the user whose credentials were used.

**I am looking for a way to configure my clients to automatically use user's own credentials when the user is accessing the mount point.**

The login user names and passwords are the same as used to access samba server.

Answer (score 3):

With [`multiuser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) mount option, users use their own credentials to access the mount point. However, this still requires the mount be available when the user access the share, and to mount the share the client needs valid credentials (if the server does not allow anonymous (guest) access).

[`pam_cifscreds`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cifscreds.1.html) can be used to cache login password which is  used to access the cifs share. Alternatively users can use [`cifscreds`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cifscreds.1.html) to provide password. In both cases, `pam_keyinit.so` should be used in pam session configuration to ensure a session keyring is established at login time.

On Debian based systems appending the following configuration should work:

*/etc/pam.d/common-session* (replace `{SAMBA_SERVER}` with IP address or host name):

```
session required    pam_keyinit.so
session optional    pam_cifscreds.so host={SAMBA_SERVER}
```

*/etc/pam.d/common-auth*:

```
auth    optional            pam_cifscreds.so
```

Comment: The above `common-session` and `common-auth` were effective for GUI login only. For ssh login, we had to insert the configs in `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Please see RHEL article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3805741 (open a free developer's account to access it). I also want to assert that `pam_cifscreds` is available in CentOS 8 or above only. I verified my comment in CentOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

1. `yum install pam_cifscreds`

(In CentOS >=8 only. It is unavailable in 7)

2. Edit files in `/etc/pam.d/`:

See RHEL article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3805741 (open a free developer's account to access it). You will not have to restart any service after doing the above changes. It takes automatic effect upon next login.

3. Mount as root user with `multiuser` option:

> mount -t cifs -o username=abc123,vers=1.0,noperm,multiuser,sec=ntlmssp //example.org/hello /mnt/hello

4. Login as non-root user through SSH. Do not use key pair. Must use password. After login, verify that your password got automatically cached by `pam_cifscreds`:

```
$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 804802868 --alswrv  4414294 100001  keyring: _ses
 775789538 --alswrv  4414294 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.4414294
 844620914 ----sw-v      0     0   \_ logon: cifs:a:example.org
```

The last one got cached by `pam_cifscreds`.

5. Now access `ls /mnt/hello` smoothly.
6. For caching password at GUI login, see [sebasth's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465793/100397).

(I verified my answer on CentOS 9)