# How to access CIFS mount with multiple users with credentials different than system login?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, cifs

A samba share with multiple users is mounted on a linux system using cifs with multiuser option. Unlike the case of a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465792/410504), the users of the system have different login usernames/passwords than the ones for accessing samba server.

Based on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465793/410504) of that question, I added `pam_keyinit.so` to */etc/pam.d/common-session*.

It seems that `pam_cifscreds` is out of option when samba access credentials are different than the the system login credentials.

With the alternative method of using `cifscreds`, the credentials added using `cifscreds add` works fine in the very same session but do not seem to be permanent. That is, if the user logs out and logs in to the system after some days, the cifs share becomes inaccessible. Access is granted again after adding the credentials using `cifscreds add`.

Is there any way of making these credentials available permanently?