# Mount samba share so it's owned by root and users of a group can read/write

Tags: permissions, samba

I'm trying to mount a samba share ho that it is owned by `root` and users of a group called `smbshare` can access it, read and write files in it.

I tried putting this in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//fs/myshare /media/share cifs credentials=/root/.cifs,rw,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,gid=smbshare,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0660,vers=3.0 0 0
```

this gets mounted as expected except my user, which is in group `smbshare`, gets `Permission denied`

```
user1@myhost:/media$ id user1
uid=1001(user1) gid=1001(user1) groups=1001(user1),27(sudo),1002(smbshare)

user1@myhost:/media$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Jan 25 15:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root     4096 Jan 18 10:11 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 root smbshare    0 Jan 25 16:39 share/

user1@myhost:/media$ ls share/
ls: cannot open directory 'share/': Permission denied
```

If I change `dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0660` to something more permissive then user can access the folder... even if it's not in group `smbshare`

For what it's worth, here the part from `/etc/samba/smb.conf` from server `fs`

```
[myshare]
    comment = my share
    path = /share/myshare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
```

Edit:

if instead of a new group `smbshare` I mount with `gid=user1` it works

`/etc/fstab`:

```
//fs/myshare /media/share cifs credentials=/root/.cifs,rw,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,gid=user1,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0660,vers=3.0 0 0
```

Comment: Please see [How to enable access control for CIFS mount point available for multiple users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768169/100397), which looks like it might help address your requirement (I only found this today)

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to implement this is to use Kerberos-based authentication and pass the `multiuser` flag with the `mount` options. Your client users will then be seen and authenticated as individuals by the server. (Note that this cannot work with `sec=ntlmssp`; you really do need to be able to use either `sec=krb5` or `sec=krb5i`.)

However, you can work-around the issue somewhat with this configuration. I have not tested it extensively and in particular I've only performed a cursory access permissions review.

1. `smb.conf`

   ```
   [global]
       unix extensions = no

   [multiuser_test]
       comment = Temporary multiuser access
       path = /samba/tmp
       guest ok = no
       read only = no
   ```
2. Client. Ensure that your users are in the `smbshare` group:

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt/net
   mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.smb_credentials,rw,gid=smbshare,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0664 //server/multiuser_test/try /mnt/net
   ```

In this instance (remember it's a work-around) client users will be seen by the server only as the single user that authenticated for the mount. Local client permissions control access to the share.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I thought that, once I mount the share on my host with proper credentials -- i.e. a user with r/w permissions -- what can do users on the host is all matter of what I setup on the host (and not on the file server). Isn't it?

Comment: Yes if you have Kerberos authentication. For example Active Directory may support this

Comment: Sorry, don't get it: in my host's `/root/.cifs` there are credentials for, say, user `john`. If I put `file_mode=0777` in `/etc/fstab`, every file read or written throug the mount will be, for samba, by `john`, is it? So it's all up to the host that defines the mount to which of its users give access to it -- and not samba users defined on another machine. There's no match between users of the two servers. Thanks

Comment: @neurino you asked for the mount to be made by (say) `root` but for your users in the group `smbshare` to be able to read/write the share. There are two ways to do this. The proper way is to use Kerberos authentication between the client(s) and server, so that each user on the client is seen and handled as that user on the server. The other is my workaround that I have suggested here

Comment: Ok, thanks @Chris, I'll check your workaround

Comment: Ok, I tried and it does not work — also the only change I spotted is adding `unix extensions = no` versus other tests I made, which I miss what should change :( I get `rm: cannot remove 'share/test.txt': Permission denied`

Comment: please see the edit I added to my question, can you explain me why only changing `gui=user1` in `/etc/fstab` it works?